# Malfatti Circles - Limiting point

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

"Three circles packed inside a triangle such that each is tangent to the other two and to two sides of the triangle are known as Malfatti circles" (for a brief historical account on this topic, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MalfattiCircles.html) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MalfattisProblem.html) on MathWorld).

Consider the triangle formed by the centers of these circles, one can draw a new set of smaller Malfatti circles in this triangle.  What is the limiting point of this process?

One thing sort of discouraging is that I tried on an isosceles triangle, unfortunately did not find the limiting point matching any of the known relevant points (e.g., incenter or [the first Ajima-Malfatti point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ajima-MalfattiPoints.html)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your question, but it should be easy enough to compute this limit point numerically for an arbitrary triangle and use the result to [search the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/search.html).

Comment: @David, Thank you for your prompt reply!  The website is extremely nice, but unfortunately, my numerical calculation (please feel free to cross-check) shows the first normalized trilinear coordinate is 1.4377 for a triangle with (a,b,c)=(6,9,13), which does not match any of the entries listed there.  It's a little disappointing, but I will mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Disappointing? This means you can claim credit for a new center!