# A chain of six circles associated with six points on a circle (in Mobius plane)

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometry, euclidean-geometry, mobius-inversion

**I found a conjecture:** *A chain of six circles associated with six points on a circle (in Mobius plane)*.

This is a generalization of the last my previous question in [Three chains of six circles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234722/three-chains-of-six-circles). (Noting that, in this configuration: $P'_1P_1P_4P'_4$ don't lie on a circle) I am looking for a proof of the conjecture as following:

**Conjecture:**

> In the [Möbius plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_plane), let a chain of six circles $(C_1)$, $(C_2)$, $(C_3)$, $(C_4)$, $(C_5)$, $(C_6)$, such that two neighbors circles $(C_i)$ meets $(C_{i+1})$ at two points $P_i, P'_i$ where $i=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$; Such that six points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6$ lie on a circle.
>
> Let $A_1$ be a point on the circle $(C_6)$, let the circle $(A_1P_1P_2)$ meets the circle $(C_2)$ at $A_2$, Let the circle $(A_2P'_3P'_4)$ meets the circle $(C_4)$ at $A_3$, Let the circle $(A_3P_5P_6)$ meets the circle $(C_6)$ at $A_4$, Let the circle $(A_4P'_1P'_2)$ meets the circle $(C_2)$ at $A_5$, Let the circle $(A_5P_3P_4)$ meets the circle $(C_4)$ at $A_6$. Then show that:
>
> - Four points $A_6, P_5, P_6, A_1$ lie on a circle.
> - Six points $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6$ lie on a circle

[image]

Comment: This is a problem for a computer, not for us.

Comment: @Anton: I disagree strongly with this attitude. The problem "for us" is e.g. realizing the outer circle as a principal homogeneous space with respect to the action of the inner circle, thereby making this conjecture "obvious" (I have no idea whether this will work - that's why it is a problem). I do agree that in its present form this question is better suited for MSE.

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer well, if it is true, it is funny observation, but one should not ask us to solve it since a computer can do it in a second. (It would be OK to say that "I checked it on computer and it is true, but can not come up with a synthetic proof".)

Comment: Dear@AntonPetrunin , some my problems, the computer must do it in some days. You can see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234053/daos-theorem-on-six-circumcenters-associated-with-a-cyclic-hexagon

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào you have nice problems, but they are not good for MO.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin The conjecture true for [Möbius plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_plane)

Comment: Please read again. @FranzLemmermeyer , I mean the conjecture true on Mobius plane.

Comment: You can erase $C_1$, $C_3$, and $C_5$, and define $A_3$ as a point lying on the circle $(A_2P_2P_5)$.

So, you have one blue circles and three black, which are convenient to consider as a three lines in the Hyperbolic (or elliptic) plane.

Now you can use parallel/antiparallel notion for definition of the points and prove your theorem by using the Ceva theorem in the Hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Dear @akopyan I am an electrical engineer. So my math is low lever. Please help me proof. I many thank to You

Comment: I am agree with Anton, I think it is better to publish these kind of problems in artofproblemsolving, people there are fans of such kind of questions and will find several interesting solutions.

Comment: Dea @akopyan I tag Eudlicdean plane geometry

Comment: Dear @akopyan I don't know why the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13511/malfatti-circles-limiting-point?rq=1 is vote up? But You don't like the my question

Comment: Nice questions, but not for this website, IMHO.

Comment: @akopyan I don't know why 4 vote up for this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18179/rouths-theorem-in-three-dimensions?rq=1

Comment: Because it was not a classical geometry question.